# Silbentrennung des Namens "Chomsky"

Tags: hyphenation

Wie lautet die sprachlich korrekte, begründete Trennung von Chomsky im Deutschen?

Unterschiedliche Werkzeuge trennen den Nachnamen von Avram Noam Chomsky unterschiedlich (siehe https://www.silbentrennung24.de/wort/chomsky/, https://www.ushuaia.pl/hyphen/?ln=de). Wie ist es richtig? Bitte eine sinnvolle Begründung mitangeben.

Etymologisch gesehen müsste man den Namen wohl auf Jiddisch, Russisch, Polisch oder Altslawisch betrachten um die ursprünglichen Silben herauszufinden... (Das Ukrainische gab's ja zu jenem Zeitpunkt genauso wenig wie das Land an sich.)

Comment: Keine grammatische Begründung, nur eine stilistische - (Nach)namen sollten, wenn möglich, überhaupt nicht getrennt werden.

Comment: http://www.bibliothek.germanistik.rwth-aachen.de/trennung.html ungefähr halbe Seite unten...

Comment: "Ansonsten ist davon – **besonders bei zweisilbigen Namen** – abzuraten"...

Comment: Der  wenige entstehende Leerraum bei einem so kurzen Namen rechtfertigt an sich nicht, dass man den Namen durch Trennung verunstaltet. Aber ich kann die Frage von einem *theoretischen Standpunkt* aus akzeptieren.

Comment: Ich fürchte, wenn du so schmale Spalten hast, dass sogar ein so kurzes Wort wie "Chomsky" dir den Satz zerschmeisst, dann hast du eigentlich ein anderes Problem. Aber - s.o

Answer (score 4):

Versuch einer Antwort, auch wenn es aus stilistischen Gründen nicht empfehlenswert ist, Personennamen, die keine Zusammensetzungen sind, [überhaupt zu trennen](http://www.bibliothek.germanistik.rwth-aachen.de/trennung.html). Aus einer rein theoretischen Sicht mag es trotzdem interessant sein, welche Regeln das Deutsche besitzt, um Namen überhaupt trennen zu können.

Die Empfehlungen des Rechtschreibrates zur Silbentrennung (§109-§113) sind für den ursprünglich russischen Nachnamen Noam Chomskys nur begrenzt anwendbar. An sich betrachten die Rechtschreibregeln nur die Praxis in der deutschen Sprache, und tun das auch für Wörter, die aus einer fremden Sprache kommen - die ursprünglichen Trennungsregeln der fremden Sprache werden nicht notwendigerweise angewandt (§113). Man muss also kein Russisch können, um einen russischen Namen zu trennen. Würde man es trotzdem tun (auch das erlaubt Regel 113), würde man wahrscheinlich darauf kommen, dass -кий (-kij) ein [gängiges russisches Suffix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Russian_words_suffixed_with_-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) ist, das man hier zur Trennung nutzen könnte (Ich gehe hier von einer ursprünglich anderen Schreibweise des Nachnamens aus, bei einer Transkribierung des Namens ins Englische wurden wahrscheinlich analog zu "rússkij" --> "Rusky" die Konsonanten der englischen Aussprache angepasst).

> Choms-ky

Von den deutschen Trennregeln am ehesten trifft wahrscheinlich §110 zu, der sagt, dass wenn zwischen zwei Vokalen (hier "o" und "y", was ich hier als Vokal sehe) getrennt wird, nur der letzte Konsonant einer Gruppe von Konsonanten in die neue Zeile rutscht

> Choms-ky

Eine Trennung nach dem "m" würde dieser Regel widersprechen, höchstens man würde das "-sk" als einen einzigen Konsonanten (§112) betrachten - dazu kenne ich aber Russisch nicht gut genug.

Comment: LaTeX meint, Chom-sky sei der default?

Comment: @LangLangC LaTex arbeitet mit algorithmischer Silbentrennung und Ausnahmewörterbuch - das kann richtig sein oder nicht...

Comment: Sicher, wie auch auf einer der OP Beispiel Seiten. Eine Trennung würde ich jedenfalls auch ganz vermeiden wollen. Nur die Suffixgeschichte bleibt noch: ist das wirklich so 'typisch'  https://be.wikipedia.org/wiki/Хомск ?

Comment: @LangLangC: Obwohl ich gerne mit LaTeX schreibe, kann einen die Silbentrennung dort schonmal zur Verzweiflung treiben. "Gleichgewicht" habe ich schon als "Gle-ichgewicht" getrennt gesehen. Solche Schoten haben mich bei der Fertigstellung meiner Diplomarbeit in den 90ern mehrere Stunden gekostet, die ich ausschließlich mit der Korrektur von Silbentrennung verbracht habe...